# Write a function with date as input in R

Tags: r

I would like to write a function that will take date as input argument and output will be day, month, week and week year. My sample code shown some error. Kindly help me
in this regards, thank you.

My Sample code as follows:

```
       myFunction <- function(date){
       date <-as.numeric(as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y",origin = "1899-12-30"))
       date$month<- strftime(date,"%m")
       date$day<- strftime(date,"%d")
       data$week<-strftime(date,"%w")
       date$week_year<-strftime(date,"%W")
       return(date$day,date$month,date$week,date$week_year)
       }
```

When I called function ,It shown error:

```
       myFunction(2016-07-26)
 Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Comment: Your format (year first, date last) does not match the "format" argument, but if it did then using `myFunction("2016-07-26")` might have succeeded. Please read `?strptime` and run through the examples.

Comment: Your fifth line contains a type "data" vs "date"

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a string. Using `lubridate` you could write

```
myFunction <- function(date){
   library(lubridate)
   t0 <- ymd(date)
   return(list(day(t0), month(t0), week(t0), wday(t0, label=F, abbr=F), year(t0)))
   }
```

Comment: I would avoid calling `library(...)` within a function definition.

Comment: @AlexIoannides: I only put it there to make the function running as a stand alone example. But I agree - I would try to avoid that although it is not always possible (e.g. if you use lubridate's `%within%`).

Comment: `lubridate::\`%within%(a, b)\`` will work as will placing the the library call at the top of any script containing function definitions.